# I need to be able to find the line number and method name in eclipse

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse

I am trying to find the line number and function name of the current function my cursor is located in. 
I need to pass this information to another function for later processing.

Here are a few more details. The editor will be the CEditor. I have a plugin that will use this data. 
I need just to display the current function and the line number it starts on. So if function XYZ starts on line number 5 and the user is typing in the function on say line 8. I need to get XYZ and line 5.

I am programing in Java but the user will be writing in C/C++.

Sorry I just noticed I missed a lot of details. I am building and Eclipse plugin that needs the method that the user's cursor is currently in. This is only when they are using the CEditor from the CDT addon.

Comment: What language are you talking about? Add the corresponding tag to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the CDT (C Development Tools) API is [here.](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/dom/index.html) The CDT supports a "DOM" (Document Object Model) which you can walk through to learn about the document being edited. Basically you need to get ahold of the `ITranslationUnit` object for the edited document, then call `getElementAtLine()` to get the `ICElement` object describing the code at a given line number. `ICElement` is the root of a big hierarchy of subclasses that describe various C language elements.

You can easily get the `ITranslationUnit` by calling `CoreModelUtil.findTranslationUnit()`, which just takes an `IFile` as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you Ernest. It worked great. One last question. How would I add a listener in my view to sense when the cursor is moved in the Ceditor?

Comment: Update to this post: Ernest ways worked great if you only needed the details from your last save of the file. If changes are made and not saved this method will be out of sync. Took a little testing to see this happening. If you use ITranslationUnit  by calling CDTUITools.getEditorInputCElement(yourEditor.getEditorInput()) it creates an ITranslationUnit that buffers the changes you make and uses the buffer instead of the file.

Comment: How do i get the function startline and its length to mark the function using ITranslationUnit ?